# GUI tools in any framework and on any platform that enable quick creation of front-ends to manage Oracle DB table data

Tags: database, forms, oracle, user-interface, code-generation

Suppose you have about 10 Gb of data sitting in about 100 existing tables in a single Oracle database, and further suppose that you will need to add a few more tables and relationships as time passes. You have limited resources and therefore would like to minimize the amount of time spent developing internally-facing tools for manual data entry/management. You can use any toolkit, any tool, any platform/OS, and your only requirement is that it is relatively easy to create/modify forms to manage data held in said tables with only knowledge of SQL, and not necessarily much or any programming knowledge (beyond the very basic concepts of control structures, variables, etc).

Think of MS Access as a point of comparison for such a tool, but without the need to actually manage the schema of the database (assume there is someone who can do that efficiently).

What tools or libraries are available? Has anyone been in a similar situation and managed to get to a place where power users could create data entry forms without developer intervention after a reasonable amount of initial setup?

Comment: Too broad; but have you looked at [APEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e25789/cncptdev.htm#CNCPT7655)?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Application Express (APEX) is the tool/framework for you.

In the simplest form:

> Create page -> select table, pick columns -> submit, viola form created to
>   insert,update,delete records.

Bjarte

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use SQL (of pl/sql), formspider could be a good tool. See [Amazing Web Applications with PL/SQL](http://theformspider.com)
It allows to to create fully responsive web applications.